# How to ensure paypal IPN's are unique before processing it?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

For `subscr_payment` and `web_accept` you have to check `txn_id` whether it has been sent to you before.

But how about

```
subscr_cancel, 
subscr_modify, 
subscr_eot, 
subscr_failed, 
subscr_signup
```

where there is no `txn_id`?

If I get `subscr_modify` 3 times from paypal how does my script know if the same IPN was sent 3 times or if the user modified their subscription 3 times?

Does anyone know if `ipn_track_id` remains the same if the same IPN message is sent multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I get subscr_modify 3 times from paypal how does my script know if
>   the same IPN was sent 3 times or if the user modified their
>   subscription 3 times?

You are only going to get a repeated IPN response from PayPal if the first one wasn't answered with a Http 200 Response Code, due to a Server 500 Error Code for example, or no answer.

> But how about
>
> subscr_cancel,  subscr_modify,  subscr_eot,  subscr_failed, 
>   subscr_signup
>
> where there is no txn_id?

The PayPal documentation is really obscure and complicated, but I found a link that might be useful, it shows a list of every variable present in each type of IPN response:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/Appx-ipn_subscription_variables.html

`subscr_id` **MIGHT** be what you are looking for, but I'm not sure if it changes with every response or not.